# Term for sets with a bijection between them

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

> If there exists an isomorphism between $G$ and $H$, we say that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.
>
> If there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$, we say that $A$ and $B$ are _______.

Is there a word that nicely fills in the blank?

Comment: Equipotent is what I'd say.

Comment: I'd say they have the same cardinality.

Comment: They are *equinumerous*, *equipotent*, or *equipollent*, or they *have the same cardinality*, or they *are of the same cardinality*, or they *have the same power*, or they *are of the same power*. I would never use *equivalent*; it has too many other meanings.

Comment: Hmmm, I'd like to coin a new term: a *bijectend*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $A$ and $B$ are in one-to-one correspondence;
- And two sets are set to be ***equivalent*** or ***equipotent*** or ***equinumerous*** if and only if there exists a bijection between them, that is, when the sets have the same cardinality. Two sets have the same cardinality (are *equinumerous*) if and only if there exists a bijection between two sets.

Comment: Here, the adjective *equivalent* should not be mistaken for the term *equal*: ***Equivalent*** sets are sets of the same cardinality. Two sets are ***equal*** if and only if each is a subset of the other. So equivalent sets need not be equal. But equal sets are equivalent.

Comment: ;-) Just saw this discussion in ["Wikipedia: Bijection"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective#Bijections_and_cardinality): the property of [equinumerosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity) (links to entry "equinumerosity")

Comment: Equivalent should be reserved for the general case of equivalence relation. Not to the particular case of equinumerosity.